# How to save the data from JSON in the state in order to generate views later

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I am new to the use of React, I have a question - how to save the data properly I receive from the API call in the state in order to generate a table/chart eventually.I need to generate a table so I can show the information for each software's host

My Api call:

```
    state= {
    hosts: [] ,
}


    componentDidMount(){
    Axios.get('https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5cffb00158196b429f524168').then(
        response => {
          this.setState( {hosts: response.data})

          console.log(response);
          console.log(response.data.host[0].meta.name);
          console.log(response.data.host[1].meta.name);
          console.log(response.data.host[0].software[0].name)
          console.log(response.data.host[0].software[1].name)

        }
    )
  }
```

When I try to get the data for an element in console.log, everything works. When I later on try to make a map,so I can show the software of each host, I don't get the data properly.I'm not certain if I make a mistake in the data saving or later, in the map function

My Table Trial:

```
 <TableSoftware hosts={this.state.hosts}>h</TableSoftware>
```

TableSoftware:

```
 <Table >
            <thead>
             <tr>

            <th className="softname">SoftName</th>
            <th className="vendor">Vendor</th>
            <th className="CPE">CPE</th>
            <th className="CVE">CVE:</th>
            <th className="CVSS">CVSS:</th>
            <th className="DESC">Desc:</th>
            <th className="LINK">Link:</th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {this.props.hosts.map(function(hoste, index) {
           return(
          <tr>
          <td>{hoste.software.name}</td>
          <td>{hoste.software.vendor}</td>
          <td>{hoste.software.cpe}</td>
           <td>{hoste.software.vulnerability.cve}</td> 
          <td>{hoste.software.vulnerability.cvss}</td>
           <td>{hoste.software.vulnerability.desc}</td>
            <td key={index}><Button variant="link" type="submit" >{hoste.software.vulnerability.link}</Button></td> */}

        </tr>)})}
```

Comment: Can you show the part where you access the state? Are you using `this.state.hosts`?

Comment: @Elphas updated

Comment: You can try doing a `console.log(this.props.hosts)` to see if your props were passed down correctly. Is the child component you are using a function or class?

Comment: They were passed down correctly.I recieved in the state the whole array from hosts. The child components is  a class

Comment: @Elphas is asking to check whether they are passed correctly into the `TableSoftware`. Can you please check `this.props.hosts` in the render method of the `TableSoftware`.

Comment: Great, I think you need to be using `this.props.hosts.host.map...`

Comment: https://imgur.com/ewX7bPt This become I from TableSoftware

Comment: With this.props.hosts.host.map(function(hoste, index)  become I TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through host and pass each host to your table component. Inside table component loop through software.

```
render() {
  const hosts = this.state.hosts.host || [];
  return (
    <div>
      {hosts.map(host => <TableSoftware hosts={host}></TableSoftware>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Loop through `hosts.software`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th className="softname">SoftName</th>
      <th className="vendor">Vendor</th>
      <th className="CPE">CPE</th>
      <th className="CVE">CVE:</th>
      <th className="CVSS">CVSS:</th>
      <th className="DESC">Desc:</th>
      <th className="LINK">Link:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {this.props.hosts.software.map(function (hoste, index) {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{hoste.name}</td>
          <td>{hoste.vendor}</td>
          <td>{hoste.vulnerability.cpe}</td>
          <td>{hoste.vulnerability.cve}</td>
          <td>{hoste.vulnerability.cvss}</td>
          <td>{hoste.vulnerability.desc}</td>
          <td key={index}><button variant="link" type="submit" >{hoste.vulnerability.link}</button></td> */}

  </tr>)
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class TableSoftware extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th className="softname">SoftName</th>
            <th className="vendor">Vendor</th>
            <th className="CPE">CPE</th>
            <th className="CVE">CVE:</th>
            <th className="CVSS">CVSS:</th>
            <th className="DESC">Desc:</th>
            <th className="LINK">Link:</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.hosts.software.map(function (hoste, index) {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>{hoste.name}</td>
                <td>{hoste.vendor}</td>
                <td>{hoste.vulnerability.cpe}</td>
                <td>{hoste.vulnerability.cve}</td>
                <td>{hoste.vulnerability.cvss}</td>
                <td>{hoste.vulnerability.desc}</td>
                <td key={index}><button variant="link" type="submit" >{hoste.vulnerability.link}</button></td>
               

        </tr>)
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      hosts: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch('https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5cffb00158196b429f524168')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({ hosts: data })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const hosts = this.state.hosts.host || [];
    return (
      <div>
        {hosts.map(host => {


          return <TableSoftware hosts={host}>h</TableSoftware>

        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

Comment: It works, I receive a table with the software for each host :). Thanks.

Comment: *To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514469/how-to-setstate-of-nested-json-array-object-of-mapped-input/56515611#56515611

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are asking how to set state.  Try using this function:

```
updateState = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      key: value,
      key2: value2,
    })
  }
```

You will need to determine what you want your key, value pairs to be, but this is the most common way to set state without mutating it.

Comment: I am asking how properly to save the data, because there are objects which are arrays and I wanted later generate views from these objects for example host.software or how properly to generate views from these nested arrays when they are in the state

Answer (score 0):

This is because API request might not be finished at the time your child component is rendered. The child component will not be able to reach the data and throw error. So what you have to do is to check whether the request is completed or not and if it is, you can let React render child component.

Answer (score 0):

Either iterate `this.props.hosts.host` or just store the host object only in the state `this.setState( {hosts: response.data.host})`

And remember that `software` is an array most require the following kind of chnages

```
<td>hoste.software[0].name}</td>
<td>{hoste.software[0].vendor}</td>
<td>{hoste.software[0].cpe}</td>
<td>{hoste.software[0].vulnerability.cve}</td> 
<td>{hoste.software[0].vulnerability.cvss}</td>
<td>{hoste.software[0].vulnerability.desc}</td>
```

Comment: I tried to store in the state and now:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cve' of undefined

Comment: That's because `software` is an array, you have to map again through it or try `software[0].vulnerability.cve`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the component is rendered before the async data arrived, you should control before to render

```
    {
    this.props.hosts &&
    this.props.hosts.host &&
    this.props.hosts.host.map(function(item, i) {
    return (
        <div key={i}>
        <h2> {item.meta.name}</h2>

        {item.software.map((sub, subindex) => (
            <p key={subindex}>{sub.name}</p>
        ))}
        </div>
    );
    });
}
```